# How to avoid data duplication in a microservice architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices

I am learning about microservices and I get very confused when it comes to data duplication. From different sources on the internet I get very different opinions on the subject, but the main conclusion that I got is that it depends if it's good on your use case or application.

Now I am struggling because I am trying to make a very simple microservice where I think data duplication is not necessary, but can't seem to think of a good alternative to it.

**My Application**

I am basically making a Twitter clone to understand the basics of microservices using AWS. To start I have 3 services:

- Timeline Service
- Post (or tweet) Service
- Follow Service

**Timeline service**
The timeline service should return the timeline of the user that asked it. It should check who the user is, that requests his/her timeline is following, get the 100 most recent posts from those users and return it to the user (that requested his/her timeline)

**Posts/tweet Service**
When a user is posting a new tweet/post, the post timeline should save the post in the post database to keep track of who posts what.

**Follow Service**
When a user wants to follow another user the follow service should keep track of that.

If I put it into an image it would look like this:
[image: Architecture]

**The problem**
My question is about the **timeline service**. Should the timeline

1. Have two (in memory) databases that also keep track of who follows who and who posts which tweets to give the user quickly their timeline back
2. Or should the timeline service call the different services to get that information?

The 'bad' thing from the last option would be that if my posts service is failing and can't send or receive requests, my timeline service also does not work and you create dependency which goes against microservice principles.

Since the last option seems the worst one to me, I would say data duplication is the better option because of response time and to keep the different services from relying on each other.
Can anyone help me to get on the right track with this problem?

Comment: You appear to be talking about denormalized data, which is a common design in modern, scalable, distributed systems.

Comment: Storing data is cheap, accessing the data is not, so modern systems optimize for the latter.

Comment: @jarmod So That would mean you say I should duplicate the posts/tweets and the followers and put it in a denormalized table in the timeline service right?

Comment: I believe that Twitter puts tweet IDs (plus author ID and metadata) into the timeline. The actual tweet content is all stored elsewhere and resolved at the last minute. Obviously there's a lot of in-memory database here, backed by disk. Some details are available from Twitter Engineering at [Timelines at Scale](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Twitter-Timeline-Scalability/), summarized [here](https://medium.com/@morefree7/design-twitter-timeline-e8f77acfbd06). Also  [here](https://stevetarzia.com/teaching/310/slides/Scalability%20Lecture%2017%20-%20Twitter%20Design%20Exercise.pdf).